# PHP - mail function from not working

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I used the below code to send email from by site. But the problem is that, the email received have some strange email address p3plcpnl0291.prod.phx3.secureserver.net 
10:45 PM (6 minutes ago) instead of info@huzup.com

The mail i got:

info@huzup.com via p3plcpnl0291.prod.phx3.secureserver.net 
10:45 PM (6 minutes ago)

to stargijo 
hello

Code:

```
<?php
$to = 'stargijo@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: info@huzup.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@huzup.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Header obtained

```
To: stargijo@gmail.com
Subject: the subject
X-PHP-Script: www.huzup.com/mailer.php for 111.92.126.41
From: info@huzup.com
Reply-To: info@huzup.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.26
Message-Id: <E1WbYrv-0004uM-Eb@p3plcpnl0291.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
Date: Sat, 19 Apr 2014 10:15:59 -0700
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - p3plcpnl0291.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [386330 956] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - p3plcpnl0291.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: p3plcpnl0291.prod.phx3.secureserver.net: authenticated_id: stargijo/from_h
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: /usr/sbin/proxyexec -q -d -s /var/run/proxyexec/cagefs.sock/socket /bin/cagefs.server 
X-Source-Dir: huzup.com:/public_html

hello
```

Comment: Can you show the e-mail header?

Comment: @pc-shooter i have added it pls check it

Comment: This seems normal to me. The 'To:' is ok, and the 'Reply-to:' also. As far as I know, the X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: is your hoster. Can you answer this mail (just as normal)?

Comment: @user3392772 Your hosting provider is probably overriding from address headers. Check with the hosting company. It might work if the domain of the from address is same as the site sending emails and the email address exists.

Comment: @JayBhatt in hosting the outgoing server is Server: p3plcpnl0291.prod.phx3.secureserver.net

is that the problem?

Comment: @user3392772. Did you try to answer this mail?

Comment: @pc-shooter yes i tried now the from address is stargijo@p3plcpnl0291.prod.phx3.secureserver.net

Comment: Maybe a cPanel configuration? Because your code looks good to me, sry I couldn't help

Comment: @user3392772 Create info@xxx email address in your cPanel, and try sending mail using hosting providers SMTP and don't use mail() function.

Comment: @JayBhatt by using the web mail in cpanel. Everything is working perfect

Comment: @user3392772 See this tutorial.  Use PHPMailer instead of Mail() function and it should fix the problem. http://ctrlq.org/code/19589-send-mail-php

Comment: @user3392772 Get SMTP details from your hosting provider. And use them in the script from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this mailheader

```
$mailheaders = "From: noreply@test.com\r\n";
                $mailheaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $mailheaders .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                $mailheaders .= "Bcc: reports@test.com\r\n";
```

hope this help!

Comment: sorry its not wokring